# C# Many Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

The question has arisen.

Suppose, there is a form on it 10 buttons.
Is there any possibility to combine these buttons in a single "structure"(union of buttons)?
To be able to work with them in style ...

ManyButtons.click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);

I need to catch only the **Events**, without properties and methods

And most importantly, without arrays.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't assign a single event handler method to each button. What is the question?

Comment: Because I think in advance. Let's say I shall fall situation with 20000 buttons, then what? Write code for each buttons? No, I shall use it.

Comment: @ObiSan: That last comment didn't make any sense at all to me. If you're trying to say that you can't assign a single event handler method to each button because it requires that you write code for each button, I think you misunderstand event handlers in C#. You can write a *single* method, and then have that code run for *every* button.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Sorry, but you probably have not noticed. I answered my question. And there is just something about what you say. "a single event handler method to each button".

Comment: Yeah, I see you answered your own question. Not sure why I should be impressed that you managed to come up with the same thing I suggested some time later. What I said is perfectly valid and correct English syntax. It means precisely what it was intended to mean, and at least 2 other people agreed with me. You have a single method assigned to each button. I'm not sure what part of that isn't clear.

Comment: oh.. sorry... now I see time when you wrote. Just I did not notice Your answer, and thought that you replay answer. I'm not English and have some problems with interpretation.

Comment: And perhaps, you helped me again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078422/event-of-radiobuttons =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about that.

I used `foreach` without `List` in style

```
foreach (var c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button)
                ((Button)c).Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Buttons_Click);
        }
```

This will help avoid a mad number of rows processing event.
And when I click on Button, my analizer checks this click and acts.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just tackle it by adding the `Button`s to a `List` and doing a `foreach` over that list.

That is, unless there is a particular reason to do otherwise?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, it's deal. I try it.

Answer (score 1):

> The question has arisen.

Ummm.... ok!

Create your own container which abstracts it, exposes the events you're interested in and behind the scenes manages the list of buttons for you. Then you'll have a simple interface in which to talk to instead of a stack of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all buttons clicks in the single event handler:

```
ManyButton1.click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
ManyButton2.click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
...
```

Inside event handler, sender parameter allows to detect, which button was clicked. You can use Tag property as button ID.

Comment: Thank you of course, but the problem is that both will have to code each button. ManyButton - is not one buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create event handler for some buttons, select them all (by holding Ctrl key), then go to properties box and create that event handler. This is the easiest and most convenient way.