# Event of RadioButtons

Tags: c#, winforms

It's my problem.

I have a few **RadioButtons**. If i click on first **Radiobutton** on form create **TextBox**, if click on second - create second **TextBox** and if i click again on first **RadioButton**, again one **TextBox**,is it possible?

Give me idea, please.

And without property **visible**.

Comment: do you want one textbox that moves and refreshes when a radiobutton is clicked?

Comment: no... I want add new TextBox if i clicked on RadioButton(second), and delete him if i cliked on RadioButton(first).

Comment: If it's help. I can write all my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (this is only one of them):

```
TextBox t;

private void radio_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (radio.Checked) {
          t = new TextBox();
          t.Top = radio.Top;
          t.Left = radio.Left + radio.Width;
          this.Controls.Add(t);
          t.Show();
        } else {
          if (t!=null)t.Dispose();
        }       
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? how doesn't it work? have you created the radio button and attached the checkedchanged event to that one?

Comment: You might have problems with Dispose() if the button is checked by default and the user clicks another. Check changed would be called and because it isn't checked it would try to call t.Dispose() which is null at that point and throw an exception.

Comment: it's doesn't work in my crap. When I create new project it works. But If I used this method. I will have many problems with name of textboxes, because they parts of array. But all the same thanks=)

Comment: seems like you've done it a terrible way and are suffering the consequences...lesson to be learned here

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much point in dynamically creating and destroying controls here.  It is just a headache, ensuring the position, size and tab order is correct.  Just make the text box visible if you like the choice:

```
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Visible = radioButton2.Checked;
    }
```

Set the textbox' Visible property to False in the designer.

Comment: I agree, but he did ask for an answer without using the Visible property

Comment: It's deal. But problem is I have a array of TextBoxes and if I used "visible"... I will have headache with position... But without "visible", in "for" all positions, sizes and tabs at good.

Comment: why does changing visiblility change your ability to alter position and size?

Comment: See http://imageshost.ru/photo/7569/id466426.html. It's borders share textboxes with each RadioButton. I can not imagine a cycle which will describe it's positions.

Answer (score 0):

See Only `foreach` and void `TextBoxes`.

```
using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Drawing;


class MyForm : Form
{
    private const int 
        HeightTextBox = 40, WidthTextBox = 25, //размер textboxes
        DistanceBetweenTexBoxHeight = 25, DistanceBetweenTexboxWigth = 25; //растояние между ними
    private int DimentionalTextBox = 3;
    private const int
        RadioButtonNumbers = 3, // количество радио кнопок
        DistanceBetweenRadiobutton = 50,
        RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionX = 5,
        RadioButtonSecondGroupStartPositionX = 0,
        RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionY = 0,
        RadioButtonSecondGroupStartPositionY = 0,
        RadioButtonSize = 25;

    public MyForm()
    {
        //Size of window
        ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(7 * HeightTextBox + 8 * DistanceBetweenTexBoxHeight,
            7 * WidthTextBox + 8 * DistanceBetweenTexboxWigth);

        //Create RaioButton
        int x = RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionX;
        int y;
        RadioButton[] DimRadioButtons = new RadioButton[RadioButtonNumbers];
        for (int i = 0; i < RadioButtonNumbers; i++)
        {
            DimRadioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
            DimRadioButtons[i].Name = "RadioButton" + (i + 2);
            DimRadioButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 2);
            DimRadioButtons[i].SetBounds(x, RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionY, RadioButtonSize, RadioButtonSize);
            x += DistanceBetweenRadiobutton;
            Controls.Add(DimRadioButtons[i]);
        }

        //Watch dimention
        // And catch even click on RadioButton
        foreach (var a in this.Controls)
        {
            if (a is RadioButton)
            {
                if (((RadioButton)a).Checked)
                {
                    DimentionalTextBox = Convert.ToInt16(((RadioButton)a).Text);
                    ((RadioButton)a).Click += new EventHandler(this.TextBoxes);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Create-Delete TextBoxes
    private void TextBoxes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb_click = (RadioButton)sender;
        int x = RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionX;
        int y = 30;
        int dim = Convert.ToInt16(rb_click.Text);
        TextBox[,] MatrixTextBoxes = new TextBox[dim, dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            {
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j] = new TextBox();
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j].Top = rb_click.Top;
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j].Name = "MatrixTextBox" + i + j;
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j].Text = i + " " + j;
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j].SetBounds(x, y, WidthTextBox, HeightTextBox);
                x += DistanceBetweenTexboxWigth;
                this.Controls.Add(MatrixTextBoxes[i, j]);
                MatrixTextBoxes[i, j].Show();
            }
            y += DistanceBetweenTexBoxHeight;
            x = RadioButtonFirstGroupStartPositionX;
        }
    }
}


class MyClassMain : MyForm
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new MyClassMain());
    }
}
```